# how to detect programmatically when a powerpoint slideshow starts

Tags: windows, powerpoint

I would like to write a windows program that would enable the user to choose a ppt file. When that ppt file starts the slideshow, my program would automatically display some message in front of the slideshow. When the slideshow is over, my program would close itself. What do I need to learn to write this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not good with VBS (which I'm sure you could use for this) but if you set your show's extensions to `.PPS` instead of `.PPT` that will force them to start playing automatically on open.  Then you won't need to see when the show starts because you'll control that.

As for opening it, if you write BATCH script you can use it to prompt for a file location but it will all be manually typed because it will load from the command window.  If a show opens, the command screen can stay open until that slideshow closes, then continue with the next line of script.

Depending on if these are your powerpoints that you want opened, I personally would put VBA script in them to trigger `On_Open` and `On_Close`  That will get you a clean customizable popup error message.

***Edit***

After doing some quick searching the `On_Open` and `On_Close` is not found in PPT, you would need to install an add-in.

Comment: I like to know how to do some features of dropbox or an antivirus software but not exactly. When a file is modified, dropbox knows immediately and uploads it to the cloud.

My program would run in background and detect a given ppt file open/close so that it can show some message. Is it possible to do with Win32 programming?